# Fetch ownerid from azure AD application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Frankly I am not a powershell expertise

```
Currently I are working to fetch azure ad application expired or about to expire details for that I have found a script but owner id is missing on that, i am aware that below line will print the owner id but that ownerid also should be present on Json object $appWithCredentials
```

$owner = Get-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $_.ObjectId -Top 1

## Below is the original script

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(HelpMessage = 'Will output credentials if within this number of days, use 0 to report only expired and valid as of today')]
    $ExpiresInDays = 90
)
Write-Host 'Gathering necessary information...'
$applications = Get-AzADApplication 
$servicePrincipals = Get-AzADServicePrincipal 

$appWithCredentials = @()
$appWithCredentials += $applications | Sort-Object -Property DisplayName,ObjectId | % {
    $application = $__
    $sp = $servicePrincipals | ? ApplicationId -eq $application.ApplicationId
    Write-Verbose ('Fetching information for application {0}' -f $application.DisplayName)
    $application | Get-AzADAppCredential -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property @{Name='DisplayName'; Expression={$application.DisplayName}}, @{Name='ObjectId'; Expression={$application.Id}}, @{Name='ApplicationId'; Expression={$application.ApplicationId}}, @{Name='KeyId'; Expression={$_.KeyId}}, @{Name='Type'; Expression={$_.Type}},@{Name='StartDate'; Expression={$_.StartDate -as [datetime]}},@{Name='EndDate'; Expression={$_.EndDate -as [datetime]}}
 }

Write-Host 'Validating expiration data...'
$today = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
$limitDate = $today.AddDays($ExpiresInDays)
$appWithCredentials | Sort-Object EndDate | % {
        if($_.EndDate -lt $today) {
            $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Status' -Value 'Expired'
        } elseif ($_.EndDate -le $limitDate) {
            $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Status' -Value 'ExpiringSoon'
        } else {
            $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Status' -Value 'Valid'
        }
}
$appWithCredentials
Write-Host 'Done.'
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither Get-AzAdApplication or Get-AzADServicePrincipal returns application owner details. You can verify this by running the commands, getting a single SP or app, and inspecting the properties. For example:

Get-AzADApplication -First 1 | convertto-json -Depth 30.

You can retrieve the application owner by querying the Microsoft Graph. I added an example to your script, which gets an Azure AD token using the Azure CLI (must be installed and logged in), then uses that token to query the Microsoft Graph for each application.

Also, on the line $application = $__, I replaced $__ with $_ to correctly reference the current item.

```
Write-Host 'Gathering necessary information...'
$applications = Get-AzADApplication 
$servicePrincipals = Get-AzADServicePrincipal 
$tokenSS = ConvertTo-SecureString -String (az account get-access-token --resource-type ms-graph) -Force -AsPlainText

$appWithCredentials = @()
$appWithCredentials += $applications | Sort-Object -Property DisplayName, ObjectId | % {
$application = $_
$sp = $servicePrincipals | ? ApplicationId -eq $application.ApplicationId
Write-Verbose ('Fetching information for application {0}' -f $application.DisplayName)

Write-Verbose "Getting application owners"
$uri = ('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{0}/owners' -f $application.id)
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri -ContentType 'application/json' -Authentication Bearer -Token $tokenSS
$owners = $response.value

$application | Get-AzADAppCredential -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property @{
    Name = 'DisplayName'; Expression = { $application.DisplayName } }, 
    @{Name = 'ObjectId'; Expression = { $application.Id } }, 
    @{Name = 'ApplicationId'; Expression = { $application.ApplicationId } }, 
    @{Name = 'KeyId'; Expression = { $_.KeyId } }, 
    @{Name = 'Type'; Expression = { $_.Type } }, 
    @{Name = 'StartDate'; Expression = { $_.StartDate -as [datetime] } }, 
    @{Name = 'EndDate'; Expression = { $_.EndDate -as [datetime] } },
    @{Name = 'Owners'; Expression = { $owners }}
```

}